# BottomSheetDialogFragment opens half

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

My `BottomSheetDialogFragment` opens half (mean not fully) when I open it.

```
fragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "my_frag")
```

- I tried `NestedScrollView` with `behavior_peekHeight` but did not work.
- Tried without `NestedScrollView`. with only `LinearLayout`.
- Tried switching height between `match_parent` & `wrap_content`

I have simple `RecyclerView` in `BottomSheetDialogFragment` layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            ...
            >
           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           ...
           />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By `BottomSheetFragment` you mean `BottomSheetDialogFragment` . To open expended sheet you need to make some changes in `onCreateDialog()`.

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog=(BottomSheetDialog)super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet =  dialog .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setSkipCollapsed(true);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setHideable(true);
        }
    });
    return bottomSheetDialog;
}
```

Just keep the layout `match_parent` no need to use `NestedScrollView`. It worked for me . Let me know if you still face problem .

In case someone is using New Material library . Which is 
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`.
Then you need change the id of Parent `FrameLayout`. So it will be .

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog=(BottomSheetDialog)super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dia) {
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dia;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet =  dialog .findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setSkipCollapsed(true);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setHideable(true);
        }
    });
    return bottomSheetDialog;
}
```

Make sure all your imports from `import com.google.android.material`in this case.

Comment: So a small thing need to be fixed by 6 lines code. This is bad about Android.

Comment: In a way its good (just to fulfill all requirement ). You see the flags `setSkipCollapsed` and `setHideable` are very useful in case you do not want to anchor the sheet in between. and there must be more.

Comment: By any chance if you are having a `EditText` in bottom sheet (like a chat view) and you struggle with `SoftInputMode` just follow [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37748167/7995966) . I have wasted 2 days to get it . Thought it  might worth to share . No other solution worked for me except this one .

Comment: Thanks @ADM, it's a useful share, but already solved problem with only using `STATE_EXPANDED`. I did not use `setSkipCollapsed` & `setHideable`.

Comment: @ADM you saved my day, thanks :)

Comment: Well Deserved man!!

Comment: I would prefer this way since it does not require hard coding any resource id



`BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = ((BottomSheetDialog)dialog).getBehavior();
            
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing your parent view so use below code to expand it into Full screen.

```
View parent = (View) inflatedView.getParent();
parent.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent);
inflatedView.measure(0, 0);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(screenHeight);

if (params.getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
    ((BottomSheetBehavior)params.getBehavior()).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
}

params.height = screenHeight;
parent.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks but I just got answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/35976745/6891563

Comment: Welcome @Khemraj